# How to compare rows after a particular column in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

SQL Gurus, I have got a problem and I have no idea how to solve it. I have a table like this in BigQuery:

```
id       ga_id        first_date     second_date
A        B            2023-08-01     2023-09-02
```

And I want to compare row like this:

```
id       ga_id        dates          rang
A        B            2023-08-01     1
A        B            2023-09-02     2
```

So how can I query this?

I'd be glad if you help me!

Comment: Is "rang" important ? I mean, does it have to be 1" for first date and "2" for second date or it depends on which date is the most recent one ?

Comment: Look for. Unpivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to compare two dates that are located in the same row :

```
SELECT id, ga_id, dates, 
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id, ga_id ORDER BY dates DESC) AS rang
FROM (
    SELECT id, ga_id, first_date AS dates
    FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, ga_id, second_date AS dates
    FROM your_table
) AS subquery;
```

Comment: thanks! You really help me after 2 days when I was trying. Yes,  it depends on which date is the most recent one, I know pivot helps me but I don't know how

Comment: I've modified my response to set the most recent date as rank 1 and the alternate date as rank 2. Though `Pivot` is useful, I find `RANK() OVER` more suitable for ranking, particularly in cases of smaller joins.

Comment: @ PeretCat Great thanks!  I've solved it with your help!

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you need solution with unpivot  - use below

```
select * replace(if(rang = 'first_date', 1, 2) as rang)
from your_table
unpivot (dates for rang in (first_date, second_date))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I will try it too for my task!  Good day!

Answer (score 0):

use below simple approach

```
select * except(first_date, second_date) replace(rang + 1 as rang)
from your_table, 
unnest([first_date, second_date]) as dates with offset as rang
```

if applied to sample data in your question - result is

[image]